# Is there a way to keep the map up while piloting?

Tags: x-rebirth

One thing I keep wanting to do is have the small mini-map in the lower-right console stay up while I'm flying somewhere.  This would make it so much easier to see where everything was, where the highways went, and possible ships in my vicinity that could be a problem.  However, the only time I see that map is when I target a highway marker.  It shows up for a small time, then goes back to saying "No Signal".  Has anyone found a way to keep this thing open while flying?

Comment: In the Steam community, Egosoft responded that they were looking into an issue where the monitor displays 'No Signal' when it should be displaying the minimap. Not sure if it's a bug or something they are going to change because we asked about it, but Egosoft is on the job.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'll have to pay attention to that thread.

Comment: Oh God, I wanted to write a tongue-in-cheek reply to the other commenter about their naive optimism about the bugfixing in a game that is riddled with bugs by a company that never properly addressed these any of the reported bugs. And then I saw who the commenter was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2.0 added minimap, it displays on info screen. It has 2 modes: tactical and navigation, you can switch modes by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.